# Xubuntu 14.04 - full-disk encryption and LVM during installation?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, encryption, lvm

Does Xubuntu 14.04 also support full-disk encryption and LVM during installation like Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, indeed, it does give the option for full-disk encryption and LVM configuration during installation.

[image]

Source: [Installing Xubuntu 14.04 on the Acer S3 Ultrabook](https://delightlylinux.wordpress.com/2014/04/28/installing-xubuntu-14-04-on-the-acer-s3-ultrabook/)

Comment: You can also choose encrypting only the /home partition during the installation